# Different output in Windows and Linux (gcc) C compilers

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, output

I have a program which solves maze, so that it finds possible route from Start(S) to Exit(E).Here is my Maze:

```
1111S11110
0000010001
110100010d
t001111110
0100000001
0111111101
1111111101
00000D01T1
0111110001
0000E01110
```

The possible route to it is :

```
Start  S  W  W  S  S  S  E  E  E  E  E  E  S  S  S  S  W  W  N  W  W  W  W  W  W  S  S  E  E  E  E   Exit
```

which is correct and i get it on CodeBlocks, However when i compile my code on dev through putty i get this:

```
Start  S  S  S  S  S  W  N  N  W  S  W  N  N  N  W  N   Exit
```

Here is my whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


// Global Variables for use
int matrixSize,startX,startY,exitX,exitY;
char src[1500] = " ";
char Ndirection[50] = " N ";
char Sdirection[50] = " S ";
char Edirection[50] = " E ";
char Wdirection[50] = " W ";

// Function for finding the array length
int numOfLines(FILE *const mazeFile) {
  int c, count;
  count = 0;
  for (;; ) {
    c = fgetc(mazeFile);
    if (c == EOF)
      break;

    if (c == '\n')
      ++count;        // end of line => increment line counter
  }
  rewind(mazeFile);

  return count+1;
}

int capLetter(char ch){
   int result = 0;
   if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
        result = 1;
   }
   return result;
}

int lowLetter(char ch){
   int result = 0;
   if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
        result = 1;
   }
   return result;
}

int isSafe(char Mazearray[matrixSize][matrixSize],int x,int y){
    if(x >= 0 && x < matrixSize && y >= 0 && y < matrixSize && Mazearray[x][y] != '1'){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;


}

void MazeSolution(char Mazearray[matrixSize][matrixSize],int x,int y,char pathArray[matrixSize][matrixSize],char wasHereArray[matrixSize][matrixSize]){
    if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x,y,pathArray,wasHereArray) == 0){
        printf("There does not exist a possible solution!!!");
    }
    else{
        pathArray[startX][startY] = 'S';
    }
}

int recursiveMaze(char Mazearray[matrixSize][matrixSize],int x,int y,char pathArray[matrixSize][matrixSize],char wasHereArray[matrixSize][matrixSize]){
    if(x == startX && y == startY){
        pathArray[x][y] = 'S';
    }
    if(x == exitX && y == exitY){
        pathArray[x][y] = 'E';
        return 1;
    }
    // check if the coordinate is safe to go(not 1)
    if(isSafe(Mazearray,x,y) == 1 && wasHereArray[x][y] != '1'){
        wasHereArray[x][y] = '1';

        // Move North
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x-1,y,pathArray,wasHereArray) == 1){
            pathArray[x][y] = 'R';
            strcat(src,Ndirection);
            return 1;
        }
        // Move South
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x+1,y,pathArray,wasHereArray) == 1){
            pathArray[x][y] = 'R';
            strcat(src,Sdirection);
            return 1;
        }
        // Move East
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x,y+1,pathArray,wasHereArray) == 1){
            pathArray[x][y] = 'R';
            strcat(src,Edirection);
            return 1;
        }
        // Move West
        if(recursiveMaze(Mazearray,x,y-1,pathArray,wasHereArray) == 1){
            pathArray[x][y] = 'R';
            strcat(src,Wdirection);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Main Function
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    // Opening the Matrix File
    FILE *mazeFile;
    mazeFile = fopen(argv[1], "r" );
    if( mazeFile == NULL )
        return 1;
    matrixSize = numOfLines( mazeFile );
    // Reading text file into 2D array
    int i,j;
    char mazeArray [matrixSize][matrixSize];

    for (i = 0; i<matrixSize; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<matrixSize; j++) {
            fscanf(mazeFile, "%c", &mazeArray[i][j]);
        }

        char eol;
        fscanf(mazeFile, "%c", &eol);
    }
    // Variables

    //Creating path array
    char pathArray[matrixSize][matrixSize];
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++){
       for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++){
            pathArray[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    // CheckPoint array
    char wasHereArray[matrixSize][matrixSize];
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++){
       for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++){
            wasHereArray[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
    // Finding start and exit indexes
    for (i = 0; i<matrixSize; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j<matrixSize; j++) {
        if(mazeArray[i][j] == 'S'){
            startX = i;
            startY = j;
        }
        if(mazeArray[i][j] == 'E'){
            exitX = i;
            exitY = j;
        }
      }
    }

    MazeSolution(mazeArray,startX,startY,pathArray,wasHereArray);
    char *data = src;
    int length=strlen(data);
    char bytes[length];
    int n=0;
    while(n<=length)
    {
       bytes[n] = data[length-n-1];
       n++;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen("path.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "Start %s Exit",bytes);
    fclose(mazeFile);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong and where to start?

Comment: Now is probably a good time to learn to use a debugger.  Did you make your maze file on Windows? Try running dos2unix mazefile.txt on the Linux box then run your program again. Either that or use something like Notepad++ on Windows to save the file with Unix line endings.

Comment: Yes, i am quiet serious.I am a student and not quiet familiar with c and  linux. Just asking for help or hint from other more experienced people in order to find my mistake. And as i know a person should not mock on smth alongside he is not helping on it.

Comment: Retired Ninja, thanks for your attention.Yeah i debugged it on windows and no errors and etc.So what do u mean by dos2unix? Can u give me more hint about it please?

Comment: It's a program on Linux to convert a file with Windows line endings to Unix line endings. You just run it like I showed.

Comment: Retired Ninja, when i converted the text file into UNIX EOL it worked fine.So does that mean it is because of the file and not because of the code?

Comment: Yes, with Windows line endings, as explained in the answer, you'd be reading on extra character on each lines, so your maze would be skewed. It might also work to put a space in your format string like " %c" since that usually causes it to eat whitespace. Anyway, just one of those things that makes cross platform code fun. :)

Comment: Aside: we like succinct questions here. It is preferred if all chatty material is omitted, like requests for help, pleading of various kinds, how long you've been stuck, hopes that someone can help, advance gratitudes of all kinds. Stick to technical writing please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOS line endings are CR-LF ("\r\n") and *nix line endings are just LF ("\n").  Change these lines `main`:

```
char eol;
fscanf(mazeFile, "%c", &eol);
```

to:

```
int c = fgetc(mazefile); // Slurp a '\r' carriage return or '\n' linefeed character.
if ('\r' == c) { 
    c = fgetc(mazefile); // slurp the '\n' linefeed character.
}
```

Comment: That should get you working on *nix and DOS, but it's not perfect.  It can be tightened up a bit with sanity checks and to cover the odd case where line endings are just '\r'.